# run script everyday on ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to run shell script on ec2 instance every day, cronjob has disabled. how can we run script using python boto3.

Do we have any options to schedule a job in aws ec2 instance without cron

Comment: what about the lambda function?

Comment: Why is "cronjob has disabled"? Do you only have some sort of restricted access to the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Event Bridge with Systems Manager to run a script every day without using cron

Comment: The "or" should be a "with". EventBridge can't do it by itself, it would have to invoke system manager

Comment: please help on how to we check if system manager agent is installed on ec2 instance or not

Comment: You can check if SSM agent is installed as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent-get-version.html

The command for Amazon Linux and Amazon Linux2 is `yum info amazon-ssm-agent`